# What are common approaches for implementing common white paper math idioms in code

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, math, implementation, notation

I am looking for a resource that can explain common math operations found in white papers in terms that that coders with minimal math background can understand in terms of coding idioms -- for loops etc.

I frequently see the same kinds of symbols in different equations and that the often result in easily comprehensible algorithms.  An overview of what the symbols mean would go a long way to making academic paper more comprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only ones i can think of that are not obvious (arithmetic, trig functions etc) and have a direct equivalent in code are sum, `Σ`, and product `Π`.

so something like `Σ a[i]` is:

```
 sum = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < len(a); ++i) sum += a[i];
```

and some related details:  a subscript (small number below the line) is often the same as an array index (so the `i` in `Σ a[i]` might be written small, below and to the right of the `a`).  similarly the range of the `i` value (here `0` to the length of `a`) may be given as two small numbers just to the right of the `Σ` (start value, `0`, at the bottom, finish value, `n`, at the top).

and the equivalent product is `Π a[i]`:

```
product = 1;
for (i = 0; i < len(a); ++i) product *= a[i];
```

*update* in the comments xan suggests covering matrices too.  those get complicated, but at the simplest you might see something like:

```
a[i] = M[i][j] b[j]
```

(where it's much more likely that the `i` and `j` are subscripts, as described above).  and that has *implied* loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < len(a); ++i) {
    a[i] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < len(b); ++j) a[i] += M[i][j] * b[j]
}
```

worse, often that will be written simply as `a = M b` and you're expected to fill everything in yourself....

*update 2* the first equation in [the paper you reference below](http://www.iiia.csic.es/~mantaras/MIREX.pdf) is `w(s[i],0) = alpha[d] * Size(s[i])`.  as far as i can see, that's nothing more than:

```
double Size(struct s) { ... }

double w(struct s, int x) {
    if (x == 0) return alpha[d] * Size(s);
    ...
}
```

and other terms are similarly fancy-looking but not actually complicated function calls and multiplications.  note that `|...|` is `abs(...)` and the "dot" is multiplication (i think).

Comment: nice answer for a vague question. Maybe few words on vector/matrix operators would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

I use this site all the time for complex mathematical operations translated to code. I never graduated high school.

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/
```

Comment: I love Wolfram, but I don't think I'd want people just grabbing stuff from it and using it without any background.  If I gave you an arbitrary function and asked you to integrate it, what would you choose?  There are a lot of different numerical integration methods, and picking the right one requires some expertise.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you enter these equations into their search field?  In regards to expertise, would it not often be sufficient to collect the candidate approaches, research them all and then select the most appropriate? Expertise is not at hand.

Comment: The Wolfram site has some nice examples, but even those presume you know enough to use their query language effectively.  It's not possible to select without expertise for some cases.  You need to be far more precise about what kinds of math operations you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

"Common math operations" depends on the kinds of problems you're used to solving.   They can range all the way from simple arithmetic (+, -, *, /) to calculus (integrals, summations, derivatives, partial differential equations, matricies, etc.)

What does "common" mean to you and your development team?

Comment: @CaseyJamesBasichis as far as i can tell, that's just arithmetic. the |...| means absolute value and the "." means multiply. but it's just very fancy looking multiplication and addition of variables - see my update 2